# Application and generalisation of Ikehara's tauberian theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

[image]

We proved in a course this version of Ikehara's tauberian theorem when the Dirichlet serie had a simple pole at s=1.
First, I was wondering how we can use this result to get an asymptotic asimtation when f extends analytically to $Re(s)>=\alpha$ with a simple pole at $\alpha$ with residue equal to 1. I would be thinking of $\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n} \sim x^{1/\alpha}$.

I would be glad to have references for any generalisation of these results when the Dirichlet series has a different form (higher multiplicity poles for example?).
Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks Ram Murty's lecture on YouTube. Did you check his text?

Comment: It is indeed his lecture. I couldn't find his text on his website!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Reuns I found out how to conclude.
First, as written above, i needed to prove that $g(t) = o(t^{\beta})$ for any $\beta > \alpha$.
I will consider another $\beta'$ lying in $]\alpha,\beta[$. I will use the fact that the convergence of $f$ at $s=\beta'$ tells us after partial summation that $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{g(t)}{t^{\beta' + 1}}$ converges and that the Cauchy tranches will be close to 0 when we go the infinity.
If $g(t)$ isn't $o(t^{\beta})$, one can choose $\epsilon >0$ and a monotic sequence $(x_{n})$ going to infinity such that $g(x_{i}) \geq \epsilon x_{i}^{\beta}$.
We will now work on this integral:
$$ |\int_{x_{n}}^{x_{n}^{\frac{\beta}{\beta'}}} \frac{g(t)}{t^{\beta' + 1}} dt| \geq \beta \epsilon x_{n}^{\beta} \int_{x_{n}}^{x_{n}^{\frac{\beta}{\beta'}}} \frac{1}{t^{\beta}}dt = \epsilon (x_{n}^{\beta - \beta'} - 1)dt $$
The right side of the inequality goes to $\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$. It is thus absurd.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\le x} a_n n^{1-\alpha}\sim x$$ then use partial summation

Comment: If I call $g(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} a_{n}$, the Abel summation tells me that i just need to show that $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{g(t)}{t^{\alpha}} dt = o(x^{2-\alpha})$. It sufficies to show that $f(t) is o(t)$ to conclude which is something a lot weaker than the result we initially want to prove. Although, i can't find out a solution in the general case, i managed to do it in the case i was interested in but my method can't be generalized

Comment: No idea of what you mean. $$\sum_{n\le x} a_n= x^{\alpha-1} \sum_{n\le x} a_n+\sum_{n\le x-1}(\sum_{m\le n} a_m m^{1-\alpha})(n^{\alpha-1}-(n+1)^{\alpha-1})$$ Then substitute $x+o(x)$ and $(n+o(n))((1-\alpha) n^{\alpha-2}+o(n^{\alpha-2}))$

Comment: oh alright, i didnt transform my sum the way you did. I wrote that $$\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n} n^{1-\alpha} = (\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n})x^{1-\alpha} - (1-\alpha)\int_{1}^{x} \frac{g(t)}{t^{\alpha}}dt$$. The way you did that is way simpler. You can check the solution i wrote as well :)